# How do I move the cursor in helm?

Tags: helm, cursor

How do I move the 'cursor' to the left/right in helm when typing a filepath? Currently my left arrow seems to be mapped to a backspace / clear word.

I'm using Spacemacs in evil mode.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the standard Emacs commands `C-f` and `C-b` for forward and backward char. It's convenient to learn those, as you can also navigate canditates with `C-n` and `C-p`.

You can also use `C-l` to go up a parent level.

For a tour on Helm, I suggest reading [Tuhdo's guide](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html).